# How to determine possible combinations of items based on item resources?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dictionary, combinations

I'm a current software development student looking to get some help with my latest self-learning project.

My coworkers and I play Settlers of Catan, so a couple of weeks ago I thought it would be a neat idea if I could make a site that would tell a person what they can buy with the resource cards they have in their hand.

For those who don't know, the basic Catan purchases are as follows:

| Building | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| City | 2 wheat, 3 ore |
| Settlement | 1 wood, 1 brick, 1 wool, 1 ore |
| Road | 1 wood, 1 brick |
| Dev. Card | 1 wool, 1 wheat, 1 ore |

What I need to do is take a players hand, which has any number of resource cards, and run it through a function that will determine a list of possible options along with the cards left over.

As an example it should return something like:

- **Option 1**: You can build 1 City, 1 Road. 1 Sheep left over.
- **Option 2**: You can build 1 Settlement. 3 Ore and 1 Wheat left over.

The function that I am currently using in JavaScript is shown below:

```
/* Below dictionary is updated via HTML inputs

Also sheep == wool, ignore the lack of using the accurate card name
*/

var resources = { 'wood': 1, 'brick': 1, 'sheep': 1, 'wheat': 2, 'ore': 3 };


/* Takes resources (your hand), then tries to determine what
the player can build with that hand */

function basicBuilder(resources) {
    var buildDict = { 'roads': 0, 'settlements': 0, 'cities': 0, 'dcards': 0 }
    while (resources['wheat'] >= 2 && resources['ore'] >= 3) {
        resources['wheat'] -= 2;
        resources['ore'] -= 3;
        buildDict['cities'] += 1;
    }
    while (resources['wood'] >= 1 && resources['brick'] >= 1 && resources['sheep'] >= 1 && resources['wheat'] >= 1) {
        resources['wood'] -= 1;
        resources['brick'] -= 1;
        resources['sheep'] -= 1;
        resources['wheat'] -= 1;
        buildDict['settlements'] += 1;
    }
    while (resources['sheep'] >= 1 && resources['wheat'] >= 1 && resources['ore'] >= 1) {
        resources['sheep'] -= 1;
        resources['wheat'] -= 1;
        resources['ore'] -= 1;
        buildDict['dcards'] += 1;
    }
    while (resources['wood'] >= 1 && resources['brick'] >= 1) {
        resources['wood'] -= 1;
        resources['brick'] -= 1;
        buildDict['roads'] += 1;
    }
    return buildDict;
}
```

This way would work fine if none of the buildings shared resources, but since some buildings use the same cards it doesn't suit my purpose. For example if you use the resources that I supplied, buildDict['settlements'] will equal 0 since all the wheat was already used up by the city.

There has to be a better and cleaner way to go about this, so my question to all of you is this:

<s>How can I best determine the players possible build choices on their turn?</s>

> As a reminder, the input will be a hand of resources in dictionary form.
> The output should be similar to:
>
> - **Option {n}**: You can build {x} Cities, {x} Settlements, {x} Roads, etc... with {x} cards leftover

Bonus points for any of the following:

- Solutions that easily allow for additional buildings later on (expansion packs)
- Solutions that can somehow accept resource trading (in Catan, 4 of a resource can be traded in for 1 of any other resource. If you own a port, this can be reduced to either 3 or 2 for one trades)
- Solutions that will still allow for the display of what the leftover cards are

**EDIT** - Reworded the question to be more specific per bots request, very new to stackoverflow. See past question above

With a hand (dictionary) full of resource cards, what is a good JavaScript way to find all the possible combinations of buildings that could be purchased?

- Each building could be purchased multiple times
- There is no maximum or fixed hand size
- When a resource is used for a building, it is removed from the hand

Comment: Here's an arbitrarily extensible system to test the hand against resource requirements and subtract them: https://jsfiddle.net/bx6510kv/

Comment: What you're looking for requires recursion iterating over all possible combinations. One way is to first generate an array of possible building options based on the total amount of cards, then filter that based on whether the current hand is sufficient.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the jsfiddle, a lot of the things you do in it are helpful (especially defining the buildings and using .map, much better than what I was doing). Some issues I'm having with it are that the building values don't seem to be accurate to what is in your hand. For example, if you set wool to 0 the output will still say that you can build development cards and settlements still. It seems that it only tests for the first non-zero resource but doesn't take into account if others are missing before it?

Comment: Figured out how to work around the 0's in the card values by changing the filter you had on the factors array from `.filter(f=>f)` to `.filter(f=>!isNaN(f))`. Definitely getting closer to a solution I can use, just need to figure out how to start the iterations to get the possibilities now.

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't test it again after adding the filter method. Anyway, yeah, l this a bit more complex of a task than it may seem at first, especially if you factor in the exchange of 4 (3, 2) cards against a new one